RDP Error to Entra ID joined PC
A users monitor has went out and before I can get to it I wanted to set them to RDP into their PC to continue working from their personal laptop.
According to Microsoft, the host device doesn't need to be Entra joined to remotely connect.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/client-tools/connect-to-remote-aadj-pc
I enabled this setting Use a web account to sign in to the remote computer and it looks like it's going to connect but then I get the error in the screenshot.
Searches say its because the remote device has a PIN but I can't find a way to test this because I cannot remove the PIN from the users account.
I tried creating a Windows Hello Disabled policy for this device only and still nothing. Frustrated...


Have you resolved this issue? Please can you share how you resolved or worked around it?
